# Handle php type page in .Net

Tags: .net, google-crawlers

I am getting an error(404 - File or directory not found.) on my .net site which shows php page

Google Crawler is giving me this error. I am unable to handle this issue in customerror of web.config.

Url is : www.site.com/index.php?page=user&action=pub_profile&id=38

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Home/Index" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound/" statusCode="404" />
</customErrors>
```

can anybody know how to handle this type of request in .net.

Comment: Going to need to see some code. Also, do you control the php site, or is it external? If the latter, remove the php tag as your question is really just about http error handling in .net

Comment: I have no php code or site in my project.. Its pure ASP.NET MVC Site.

Comment: OK, good, you removed the tag. Now you need to edit your question to show the .net code that is throwing the error, and also provide the actual error message. Also you probably want to add the tag for which ever .net language you are using (c#, vb.net etc)

Comment: I am getting 404 - File or directory not found.
and i have handled 404 in my web.config custom error, but it is not working with this specific url. Other than this, all .net mvc urls are getting handled by this correctly.

Comment: Ok, so are you saying the redirect in your web.config is NOT being used if you attempt to access that url on your site? But if you enter some other fictional url `www.site.com/non-existant.cfp` it is used?

Comment: Yes, it is only not handling index.php type url . Even it is not entering in Application_Error event in global.asax.